# Losing observable stream in child component

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to pass an observable feed called `articles` to a child component but I keep losing the stream. I have a parent component that feeds an observable into a child component as follows:

```html
<app-section-article-wrapper [articles]="articles$ | async" *ngFor="let section of sections$ | async" [section]="section"></app-section-article-wrapper>
```

The observable feed is updated by choosing a filter from a select box. I'm intermittently losing the articles inside the child component, they just appear as null. My child component simply accepts them as input:

```ts
@Input() articles
```

Can anybody please advise?

Comment: Where are those things coming from? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I miss to see a "articles$ | async as articles"

Comment: `articles$` is `Subject`?